# Timeline doesn't show review task results if you don't have the minimum reputation required to access any review queue

Tags: bug, status-review, review, privileges, timeline

It seems that on sites where you don't have the [access review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege, you don't see the results of reviews in the timeline. [Example](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/posts/32193/timeline):

[image]

However, you are able to click on the review itself to see the results, so it makes no sense to hide it. Even if it did, it's not really consistent: on sites where you have access to First questions but not e.g. Suggested edits, you still see the results for Suggested edits in the timeline.

Comment: Yep, this seems easily reproduced by just opening the linked timeline in an incognito window. The review's listed there, but not the result of the review – but you can just as easily see the the result by clicking on the review type entry listed there.