# Moderator tagging own question

Tags: discussion, tags, moderators, ethics, moderator-tags

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379896/timeline-doesnt-show-review-task-results-if-you-dont-have-the-minimum-reputati) asked recently, a moderator asked about a bug. Later, another moderator tagged it as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review).

Can moderators tag their own questions with [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) (I am assuming so)? If so, why didn't the moderator do so with the question? Or was the moderator planning to see if other people could reproduce it?

*I do not plan to criticize anything; I am just curious.*

Comment: Ok, I found it now; first list item: [*"Can add/remove moderator tags (status-*, featured) tags to questions"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344161)

Comment: Here's an earlier example, called instead of "moderator tags" also called "status tags" see [Status-* tags - moderator only?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7677)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rules which Meta Stack Exchange moderators need to follow regarding adding \[status-review\] tag in conflict of interest cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375604/rules-which-meta-stack-exchange-moderators-need-to-follow-regarding-adding-stat) - In particular, Journeyman Geek's [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375604/622284).

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure, my question is quite similar yes, but I am sort of looking at the question itself and why the mod didn't tag it himself - assumed mod was waiting for others to try and reproduce it (my question can still easily be closed as a dupe - since I am not sure, I will wait a little to see what others think) Thanks for the link, it answers part of my query

Comment: That was a CM doing the tagging; not a mere mod. I'm happy they deem it important enough, FWIW I did nothing to accelerate the process.

Comment: I think a 'useful' way to think of it is as a ticketing system - we have the ability to raise a ticket, though with limited visibility of what SE is doing internally, we mostly stick to high urgency or things that are on the roadmap. We *can* retag stuff - and if its urgent, sure, but its usually sufficient to let other mods or staff to review it without prompting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, moderators can add any [status-*] tags  (or [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)) to their questions. Sometimes the moderator who asked will have another mod add the tag as to [avoid the appearance of a conflict of interest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375604/323179), but that's not what happened there because the user who added the tag is staff. The question probably wasn't tagged with a status tag early on because it's not an urgent issue. (Adding [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) adds a question to the internal SE bug/feature tracking system.)

If you need an example of a mod adding [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), see [ELU Meta — revision 2](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/15310/revisions) (some mods have absolutely no shame).

Comment: Absolutely unacceptable abuse of moderator abilities. ;)

Comment: @Spevacus If you're going to report me, I hope that you also mention the fact that I also edit my own comments 7 minutes after posting them :p

Comment: I bet you edit your own chat messages 5 minutes after posting them, too. Zero shame.